# Set the width of \TextField to the width of the table width

Tags: width, cell

I want my `\textfield` width to fill the width of the table. For now I have this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,2pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}% load last unless you know a package should be loaded later

\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}

\hline
\textbf{Description} & \textbf{M/P} & \textbf{Was shipped before to customer}\\
\hline
USB Isolator & 114991949 & \CheckBox{Yes:} \CheckBox{No:}\\
\hline
Power strip & \TextField{Version:} &\CheckBox{Yes:} \CheckBox{No:}\\
\hline
White Ferrite bead & 28A2029-0A0 & \CheckBox{Yes:} \CheckBox{No:}\\
  \hline
  \TextField[name=r1]{} &\TextField[name=r2]{} &\TextField[name=r3]{} \\
   \hline
  \TextField[name=r4]{} & & \\
   \hline
   & & \\
   \hline 
  \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Which gives me this:

[image: width of \TextField to the width of the table width]

I would like to have this:

[image: filed width]

I tried using: `\ttabbox{\TextField[name=r2]{}}` . But it did not change anything. I also tried `\TextField[name=r2, width=p{width}]{}`.

I cannot find how can I get the width of the cell and use it on my \textfield, or if there is another way to make the width of the \textfield to be the width of the cell.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you, I edited the document.

Comment: us p-type columns in the tabular, then you can use `width=\linewidth` in the text field.